# IIS PHP7 FastCgi Intemittent HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: fastcgi, iis-8.5, php-7.3

I'm running PHP7 under IIS8.5 with FastCGI

IIS is returning the following error occasionally:

`HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error`

`C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly`

IIS logs the errors as in the following example

```
2021-05-05 13:22:20 10.10.0.15 GET /pedido/status1.php - 443 - 152.250.143.188 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/90.0.4430.93+Safari/537.36 https://www.***.com/pedido/pedido2.php 500 0 255 2718
```

FastCgi properties are the following:

- Instance MaxRequests: 10000
- Max Instances: 0
- Standard Error Mode: ReturnStdErrIn500
- Activity Timeout: 90
- Idle Timeout: 300
- Queue Length: 1000
- Rapid Fails per Minute: 10
- Request Timeout: 90

I appreciate any help that can tell us if we are misconfigurating IIS

Tks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the solution below:

1. There's a fairly good chance you're missing the correct VC++ runtime for the version of PHP you're running, try installing [VC++ runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).
2. If you have installed the VC++ runtime, please check whether you have installed 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: I understand that without VC++ IIS would report error all times, isn't it? FastCgi error appears intermittently, most of the times application is running fine

Comment: you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Rapid Fails PerMinute is too low.

Just change the Rapid Fails PerMinute to the default of 90,

Rapid Fails PerMinute: Specifies the maximum time allowed for a request to the application. If a FastCGI process takes longer than the specified time on a single request, it is terminated. The default value is 90 seconds.